# python dictionary type error sum wont calculate

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
def calculate_average_rating(input):
    final = {}
    for key in input.keys():
        avg = sum(input[key])/len(input[key])
        final[key] = avg
    return final
```

My code is intended to take a dictionary input, "The Lion King (2019)" : [6.0, 7.5, 5.1], "Titanic (1997)": [7], and calculate the average of the scores of each movie and return in a dictionary form. For example: "Spider-Man (2002)": [3,2,4,5]}  ==>   {"Spider-Man (2002)": 3.5

The error I'm getting is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-134-8a09678d0016> in <module>
----> 1 calculate_average_rating(ratingData)

<ipython-input-133-3a0eaee00f3b> in calculate_average_rating(input)
      2     final = {}
      3     for key in input.keys():
----> 4         avg = sum(input[key])/len(input[key])
      5         final[key] = avg
      6     return final

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: dont use `input` as a var name - it is a python built in

Comment: Even changing the input name still didn't change anything

Comment: Perhaps some of the ratings in a dict entry are of type `str` instead of being `float` or `int`?

Comment: 'Toy Story (1995)': ['4.0', '4.0', '4.5', '2.5', '4.5', '3.5'], 'Jumanji (1995)': ['4.0', '4.0', '3.0', '3.0', '3.0', '3.5'], this is my input

Comment: Your input is strings: `'4.0',` you need to convert those to floats. The function itself works fine if you actually give it numbers.

Comment: Hey, wait a minute, you said your input was: `"The Lion King (2019)" : [6.0, 7.5, 5.1]`

Comment: How do I do that

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to pre-process the ratings:

```py
def calculate_average_rating(ratings):
    final = {}
    for key in ratings.keys():
        film = [float(item) for item in ratings[key]]
        avg = sum(film)/len(film)
        final[key] = avg
    return final
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the 1 liner below

```
import statistics 
data = {"The Lion King (2019)" : ['6.0', '7.5', '5.1'], "Titanic (1997)": ['7']}

avg = {k: statistics.mean([float(x) for x in v]) for k,v in data.items()}
print(avg)
```

output

```
{'The Lion King (2019)': 6.2, 'Titanic (1997)': 7.0}
```

Comment: Not the downvote, but given the first version of the question, their code works fine. This doesn't address the error they were getting -- it just makes a one liner that does the same thing and raises the same exception.

Comment: @Mark Code was updated - still 1 liner but it handles the strings as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_average_rating(input):
    final = {}
    for key in input.keys():
        avg = sum(map(lambda x : int(x),input[key]))/len(input[key])
        final[key] = avg
    return final
```

Comment: Why are you using a lambda expression?

Comment: it can convert any string or float data into integer type so we don't get Type Error.

Comment: But **why the lambda expression**? It's completely pointless. You just want `int`... Why `lambda x: int(x)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, even more confusing is fact that values are actually float and `int()` call will simply throw an exception.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.